# Is there a way to stop the direct execution of single-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Due to the reason explained below I don't want to allow the user to directly access the `single-product.php`. What I mean is that user shouldn't be able to directly access the link   `http://example.com/product/product-1/`

The person show only be able to access this link from the site by clicking the link.

Is it possible???

**Reason**

Client has one product which he wants to sell in 4 zones and he don't want to look the site like eccomerce at all

1. UK
2. US
3. Europe(all countries)
4. India

For all the locations shipping is free but prices are different

Process of flow is  till UK, US & India---

On home  page user is asked to select the country where he wants  the shipment.

Accordingly the user gets to the page of single product specific to that country. Now selects the quantity of product and add it to the cart. Cart is emptied if anything was there earlier and redirected to checkout page.

In case of UK, US , India,   I have made 3 products in three categories(category names according to the countries code).

Then according to the category of the product in the cart, on the shipping page the country is pre-selected.

But in the case of Europe it will be too cumbersome process to create products & categories for all the countries with in Europe as the price is same for all over the Europe.

So  what I am planning is to make a select option at home page with values as country codes. And then depending upon that value we can pre select the country on check out page.

But now only catch is user shouldn't be allowed the direct access.
Thanks

Comment: reason? You can have user authentication to avoid access to restricted content.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible, because can access with the link with link click and directly from the page is similer

Comment: If you don't want the user to access it, don't expose it via requests but use it as a library. If there's a URL to it, people will find a way to use it.

Comment: "doesn't want to look the site like eccomerce at all" ok, but if you're selling something it is inherently ecommerce. You could use `template_direct` to redirect single products to the homepage or filter `the_content` to show some kind of "restricted" message if a location cookie/session variable hasn't been set. However, I think it might be best to ask for the user's shipping location on the single product page. Then once set, you can show the correct price.

Comment: @helgatheviking that is the issue , client wants the flow to be the same i.e select the country first. I think your location cookie session variable method will work but i don't know how to implement that. I guess the best would be to make the products for all the countries in Europe as this would have taken less time than i am trying to do it the other way for last 1.5 days. Any ways thanks

Comment: Use whatever system you were planning on using on the homepage to set the country and use it on product page, or really, *any* page. Have you looked at the [WooCommerce Price by Country](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocomerce-price-by-country/) plugin?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**(in current_theme_folder/**`functions.php`**)

```
function check_authorization() {
    if(is_single())
    {
        if($_POST){
            //AUTHORIZE
        }else{
            //UN AUTHORIZE
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'check_authorization');
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **NO**. There is no 100% foolproof way to do that.
HTTP_REFERRER and using sessions doesn't guarantee that a user can't access that url (after authenticated, or after forming a post request on his own, if you decide to allow only POST). If a url exists, and people can follow it from your application, someone will be able to access it directly in the browser or build a request to retrieve it.

You could of course pass along some variables in the URL with that request (again, its not what you are asking), and make url temporary, insert a time based token into database that will invalidate that URL after a period of time. But this is another topic, there are other methods too, but again they are not relevant to the question you ask. I am merely pointing you to look for different solutions to your problem.

The main question however is still not answered from you: why would you need that? If a user can access the url from your application, and you secured it there, there is no need to avoid a direct access to the same url.

**EDIT:** 
Now that you have majorly rewritten your original question, and you want to have country based products, you could simply include locale in the url, and products will be of different properties across different regions. Like http://example.com/uk/product, http://example.com/it/product. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

You could also keep you country in session, and url will be the same for everyone.

But again remember, if a URL is accessible in USA, there is no way to prevent Europe users accessing it too. Unless, you do some ip-to-country mapping, where you will automatically detect IP of the client, and restrict his access to other regions. Again this technique, could be overcome using VPNs and proxies, so not 100% working solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation . So i guess creating products for all the countries is the only way out.

Comment: why creating products for all the countries? you can keep the same products, just change shipping,tax, etc details for the countries

Comment: Then how would i get the country from the user on home page and display price accordingly on single product page and then use the same contry selected at first step to re select the country at the checkout page. I know the logic is awkward but how can you say to the client

Comment: you hold country value in  $_SESSION, which you define when user selects a country on the first page, or if user lands directly on some countries page, you by default select a value for country.. So you either get it from URL /us/products, or you store in session, if user hasn't selected a country, you set him with a default country value. There is really no other option. It will be another question, open it on SO, as for you question- I think I answered it, please accept answer, and if you want to discuss further, open a new question.

Comment: you could also take a look at this... [`$location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/f52b01827998198582983da56cdfdc402c238869/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L719)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] environment variable to check if the request came from your website or not.

Comment: you can always spoof that, not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Yes , there is may way to do this

- You can set a session and when the user visit product  page directly you can verify the session if exist  but this maybe not that much good .
- You can check where user come from by using

  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

So you can know if he come from correct place or he just access the page directly .

- other way is , put your product  link on a form typed as post and put some hidden value on it such id or name , then on the product page you can check if the user comes from correct page by :

  ```
  if($_POST['url_link'])
  {

    print("Correct url")

  }else{
      redirect("Host URL")
  }
  ```

Comment: if you want foolproof solution , You can prevent any direct access to the page and use Route .